# Idiomatic clojure question on sequence transformation

Tags: clojure

I am learning Clojure, and I need a push in the right direction with this problem I came up with.

I have a sequence of events.  Each event includes a 'date'.

```
(def events
  [
   [1509 :marry   "Catherine of Aragon"]
   [1527 :unmarry "Catherine of Aragon"]
   [1533 :marry   "Anne Boleyn"]
   [1536 :unmarry "Anne Boleyn"]
   [1536 :marry   "Jane Seymour"]
   [1537 :unmarry "Jane Seymour"]
   [1540 :marry   "Anne of Cleves"]
   [1540 :unmarry "Anne of Cleves"]
   [1540 :marry   "Catherine Howard"]
   [1542 :unmarry "Catherine Howard"]
   [1543 :marry   "Catherine Parr"]])
```

I want to convert this into a lazy timeline, i.e. a sequence containing one vector per year.  Starting with the year of the first event, and continuing to infinity.

```
[[[:marry "Catherine of Aragon"]] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [] [[:unmarry "Catherine of Aragon"]] [] [] [] [] [] [[:marry "Ane Boleyn"]] [] [] [[:unmarry "Anne Boleyn"] [:marry "Jayne Seymour"]] ...]
```

Comment: I'd consider re-formatting to adhere to lisp/clojure convention of putting the trailing parens on one line, see: http://techbehindtech.com/2010/12/09/clojure-good-coding-guidelines/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
(def timeline
  (let [events-by-year (group-by first events)]
    (map #(map next (events-by-year %))
      (iterate inc (reduce min (keys events-by-year))))))
```

Quick test:

```
=> (take 30 timeline)
(((:marry "Catherine of Aragon")) () () () () () () () () () () () () () () () ()
 () ((:unmarry "Catherine of Aragon")) () () () () () ((:marry "Anne Boleyn")) ()
 () ((:unmarry "Anne Boleyn") (:marry "Jane Seymour")) ((:unmarry "Jane Seymour"))
 ())
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest something like:

```
(defn timeline
  ([] (timeline (ffirst *events*) *events*))
  ([time evts]
     (let [[now later] (split-with #(= time (first %)) evts)]
       (cons (map rest now)
             (lazy-seq (timeline (inc time) later))))))
```

Test:

```
user> (take 30 (timeline))
(((:marry "Catherine of Aragon")) () () () () () () () () () () () () () () () () () 
 ((:unmarry "Catherine of Aragon")) () () () () () ((:marry "Anne Boleyn")) () () 
 ((:unmarry "Anne Boleyn") (:marry "Jane Seymour")) ((:unmarry "Jane Seymour")) ())
```

I'm assuming that the list of events is infinite as well :)

*Updated with improvements, and borrowing a couple of ideas from cgrand (thanks :)*

Comment: Thanks.  It breaks when there are more than one event on the same date i.e. [1515 :c] [1515 :d].  However, there are a lot of good pointers in there, so maybe I can figure the rest out myself.

Comment: @GHZ Ah, missed that. Well, cgrand's was nicer anyway :) Refactored, leaving as a second option.